# How can a variable be overridden if not passed by reference?

Tags: php, oop, variables, object

This is more a discussion topic than a 'help me' question.

I have just come across a strange problem. A variable (object) is being overridden when not passed anywhere.

Example;

```
var_dump($node->title);
$entity = $server->pull($item);
var_dump($node->title);
```

The two var_dumps display two different values.

$item is an unrelated string.

At this point, I dont think the contents of the 'pull()' method are relevant - I'm not curious about WHERE this is being overridden, I'm curious about HOW its being overridden.

How can PHP alter the variable unless it has been passed to the method?

There are no references in my function, node is passed direct;

```
function my_function($node) {
```

<s>Even if I make a clone of my object</s>
Even if I rename the var

```
$my_node = $node;
```

<s>The cloned object is *still* overridden.</s> 
The renamed object is *still* overridden (ie, its not related to the name.)

I would love to know how this is possible. How can pull() (or associated methods) over ride a variable that they have not been given?

I need to reiterate; I don't care **where** the value is being changed, I care about **how** it is being changed when it isn't passed to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this:

```
$my_node = $node;
```

Doesn't actually clone the object. If you change $my_node, it will still be reflected in $node because both are just pointers to the object, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

So, possibly something is acting on $node or a copy of $node and therefore changing the object.

See this example from the link above:

```
class A {
    public $foo = 1;
}  

$a = new A;
$b = $a;     // $a and $b are copies of the same identifier
             // ($a) = ($b) = <id>
$b->foo = 2;
echo $a->foo."\n";
```

Even though we did $b = $a, if we change the property on $b, it changes the property on $a.

Comment: Ahh yes, my mistake and thanks for clearing that up (I updated my question to reflect this.) But that still doesn't explain how it is being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

So, an important part of OO in PHP5 is that objects are **always** passed by reference, which I'd totally forgotten.

This makes it more than likely that the method being called has access to my object via a reference and makes this question seem silly. :)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Please accept the existing answer that is actually pointing to exactly that. Or at least accept *any* answer ;)